# Unauthorized Disclosure of Private Repository

Tags: github, repository, private

I am the owner of a private repository in GitHub that I created several years ago (2019). To my surprise, I recently discovered that a public repository, with a strikingly similar name and content, was created in May 2022. This public repository should not exist, as I distinctly remember removing or making my repository private before the end of 2021. What can I do to remove the repository or to contact with the person that made public my code?

I have inspected the activity of the user who created the repository, the only thing I know is that they created the account and the repository on the same day, and that they have no further activity.

Please note that, to respect privacy and security, I have refrained from sharing specific details about the repositories involved.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. Maybe they cloned it when public then created their own repo to push the clone to when they realised the original was gone.